# Split One Column into three then delete one column SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data where the date and time are in one single column.

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXCmt.png)

What I am looking to achieve from SQL code is to split out into three columns (Date/Time/Milisecs) then delete the third column (Milisecs) leaving the table with new column names - Start_Date & Start_Time - as shown here.

[Outcome_Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vn9uG.png)

I have tried a substr function but can't quite figure out how it should be written

```
Select *
Select WTR_Date_time
substr (help here)
from time_split_test
```

Comment: What is WTR_DATE_TIME column's datatype? Maybe you do need SUBSTR (if it is VARCHAR2), but maybe you don't (if it is TIMESTAMP).

Comment: It is a General datatype.

Comment: There's no such datatype in Oracle.

Comment: Ah sorry, I’m in excel head. It is a text datatype

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `WRT_DATE_TIME` has the data type `TIMESTAMP(3)`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE time_split_test (wrt_date_time TIMESTAMP(3));
```

Then you can add generated columns to get the date, time and milliseconds components:

```sql
ALTER TABLE time_split_test
  ADD WTR_Date DATE
               GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TRUNC(wrt_date_time));

ALTER TABLE time_split_test
  ADD WTR_Time INTERVAL DAY(0) TO SECOND(0)
               GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
                 ( TRUNC(wrt_date_time, 'MI')
                   + TRUNC(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM wrt_date_time)) * INTERVAL '1' SECOND
                   - TRUNC(wrt_date_time)
                 ) DAY TO SECOND
               );

ALTER TABLE time_split_test
  ADD WTR_MS NUMBER(3,0)
             GENERATED ALWAYS AS (MOD(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM wrt_date_time), 1) * 1000);
```

Then, for the sample data:

```sql
INSERT INTO time_split_test (wrt_date_time) VALUES (SYSTIMESTAMP);
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   time_split_test;
```

Outputs (with default NLS session settings):

> | WRT_DATE_TIME | WTR_DATE | WTR_TIME | WTR_MS |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 16-MAY-22 13.35.28.570 | 16-MAY-22 | +0 13:35:28 | 570 |

---

If you want to round the milliseconds to the nearest second then you can use:

```sql
UPDATE time_split_test
SET WRT_Date_Time = CAST(WRT_Date_Time AS TIMESTAMP(0));
```

Then the table would contain:

> | WRT_DATE_TIME | WTR_DATE | WTR_TIME | WTR_MS |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 16-MAY-22 13.35.29.000 | 16-MAY-22 | +0 13:35:29 | 0 |

---

If you want to truncate the milliseconds to the start of the current second then you can use:

```sql
UPDATE time_split_test
SET WRT_Date_Time = TRUNC(wrt_date_time, 'MI')
                   + TRUNC(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM wrt_date_time)) * INTERVAL '1' SECOND;
```

Then the table would contain:

> | WRT_DATE_TIME | WTR_DATE | WTR_TIME | WTR_MS |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 16-MAY-22 13.35.28.000 | 16-MAY-22 | +0 13:35:28 | 0 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=153925c193d7ab9ea1b4ffdbf9d53248)*